# "missing space" bug in comments. (on OSX)

Tags: bug, status-completed

For example... [iOS 8 Black background instead of transparent cell background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522594/ios-8-black-background-instead-of-transparent-cell-background)

Missing space just before the bold words:

[image]

Full example ...

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps someone make more money cheers!

---

As discovered by Anthony below, it DOES NOT affect Windows8.1 browser:

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? I see a space between "there" and "only".

Comment: Hey - Just the normal browser on a Mac.

Comment: check out screenshot awesomeness my man

Comment: Looks like it's a browser or Mac issue. I'm seeing a space in Firefox 34.0 on Windows 7 64-bit. Can you try another browser and see if it's still a problem?

Comment: similar issue reported at Programmers meta for Safari (7.1) on the Mac (10.9.5): [Missing and extra spaces in comments](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6948/31260)

Comment: @gnat Hmm. No repro in Chrome on Mac 10.8.5. Sounds like a browser problem rather than something on our end.

Comment: @AdamLear note, that it is showing up in Safari on iOS also.  I haven't updated to the latest iOS and thus no changes to the rendering engine there.  That this is *now* a problem might suggest that you reexamine changes to the associated css.

Comment: Reproduced. Out of town right now, so things are a bit out of whack, but will fix ... soon.

Comment: "No repro in Chrome on Mac 10.8.5." -- umm, it's in Safari.  Note the images I bothered posting!  Just BTW "who uses chrome"?  We don't do much WWW development but surely a professional WWW shop like your good selves would test with the main browser used by the planet?  Anyways hope it helps!

Comment: As a curiosity, why would anyone downvote a bug report?

Comment: @JoeBlow Uhh, Chrome is the most widely used web browser, and [most sources agree that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers) Safari is the second *least* common. Why would you assume everyone uses OS X? Even if they did, why would you assume that people wouldn't rather switch to (arguably) a "better" browser, like almost everybody I know?

Comment: (As for the downvote thing, I have no idea. +1 from me.)

Comment: Hi Knob!  Sorry I meant on a "mac".  There is almost no "Chrome" use on mac.  For working professionals like youse and me (the only thing I ever use on these macs is "Terminal" and Xcode) it's easy to forget how "consumer" the civilian out there is. We are not a www shop, but for my www brethern, regarding making it work on macs, nobody even bothers with "opera" "chrome" or whatever.  For sure, for windows 8, nt, 7, whatever, as i understand it my www brethern must get it working on chrome, right!  Rock on ...

Answer (score 2):

I made a noble effort to get [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240721/155160) working in Safari. There's some combination of our CSS/layout and the CSS directives that makes this work *sometimes*, but not reliably. Ultimately the win here from getting it working is relatively minor, so for now I reverted the changeset that introduced this issue.

The update will be live in the next production build.

We'll just have to revisit this if/when the time comes to see about full support for RTL languages.

Comment: here's a **test** ... seems to **work** **perfectly** I think? half**word** even. it seems **perfect** to me now - heh good one