# Poor conduct of high reputation user and abuses that follow

Tags: support, moderation, review-abuse

Please see the following question, which I feel was moderated only because I called out the user "creack" for his initial response and comments (which he or someone has deleted): [Do I want a container handling multiple requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856042/do-i-want-a-container-handling-multiple-requests)

Rather than instantly flagging the question and leaving it, he flagged *and* answered, including a quip at the start of his initial response (which I edited, while preserving potentially useful content).  The quip in his responses included a remark about my skills and a very dismissive instruction to "go see the documentation", without so much as a link to a relevant section.

*(Later, my question was marked as "off-topic", which is obviously in error as my question is about specific technologies as indicated in the tags.)*

Obviously lots falls between the cracks in a system like SO and a majority of the time serves the general good quite nicely.  But I think this is a circumstance where an expert mis-stepped and was unwilling to admit that he was too harsh.
Instead, my question has been buried out of spite to hide the fact that his initial response was extremely rude and unhelpful.

I'm hoping to see this question restored at least so that others might be able to answer it, or such that I can come back and answer it myself once I've completed my research.

I do not think it's fair that just because he was unable to understand my question, that I should be unable to ask it.

Comment: You're not alone: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault

Comment: I can't judge the abuse but as I commented on the other meta post about this same question: I don't agree with its closure nor that the question is off-topic.

Comment: I don't see any inappropriate or abusive behaviors by that user.  The only inappropriate behavior that I'm seeing here is yours, in that you're personally attacking a user for having the audacity to try and help you solve a your problem.  Clearly that was a mistake on his part, one that I expect he now realizes.

Comment: *"Instead, my question has been buried out of spite to hide the fact that his initial response was extremely rude and unhelpful."* - I think you're taking things *way* too far here and are being way too easily offended by something simple. He did not close your question single-handedly. Four other people were involved it. You took a very unconstructive approach to trying to get your question reopened here.

Comment: *I think you confuse what is Docker. Please take a look at docker.io and the tutorial.* does not appear to be intended to be a quip. It may be worded poorly, but I don't think he was trying to be rude.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you as well.  Code can and will be involved. Regarding the conduct issue...If you review creack's activity, you'll see that he actually rolled back his rude response.  Which I subsequently re-edited. He seemed quite resolute on getting his barbs in.

Comment: @Compass - Is it possible to review the comment history?  The appear to have been deleted, but there was more in there.

Comment: @Omega That is not an insult.  It is a helpful comment pointing out a misunderstanding on your part.  Would you prefer to be unaware that you had a misunderstanding about a fundamental concept?

Comment: @Omega I assume that would be a diamond mod's power. The comment war likely started because of the rollback war. The statement by itself passes the Mr. Rogers reading test.

Comment: @rene How is this *not* a sysadmin topic?  This question looks to be very clearly not a programming question.

Comment: A misunderstanding is implicit here.  I'm on a questions/answer site.  I don't need to be beat on the head for asking.  And again, being told to read docs with no links would definitely have gotten *my* answer flagged (which is why I always include references and excerpts).

Comment: @Servy I'm not claiming it in NOT a sysadmin topic. I claim it is also a tool used by developers, as I learn from the tag wiki....but I'm happy to be wrong...

Comment: @Omega So then you're simply saying that the content is simply not useful because the reader will already know it, not that it's rude or in any way inappropriate.  If you feel that it's just obvious and "goes without saying", then that's an appropriate reason to remove it, but clearly the author disagrees on that point, and feels that it is a point worth stating explicitly because it's *not* obvious.  I feel it's his decision to make in that regard.

Comment: @rene Pretty much the entirety of sysadmin work involves tools used by programmers, but that doesn't make them all on topic on SO.  SO is about tools used by programmers *when programming*.  Not tools used by programmers, when doing sysamin work instead of programming.

Comment: @Servy - I don't think there's any circumstance online or in person where I would open up my response to someone with a negative appraisal of them.  It's rude.

Comment: @Servy the times are changing: *The same container that a developer builds and tests on a laptop can run at scale, in production* the fields are not so strictly divided as they once were....

Comment: @rene The fact that the same person may be performing both tasks doesn't mean that they aren't separate tasks, or that you can ask about either topics on sites about the other.  There is a site for that, and it's not SO.

Comment: @Servy Let's agree to disagree. Now I want some ice cream.

Comment: @Omega Certainly you shouldn't use an ad hominem attack (which that wasn't; but it also wasn't particularly nice). That said; there are plenty of XY questions where I would open with "Don't do that!". "Negative" response can definitely lead off answers.

Comment: @Servy - It's not exclusively for systems though, there are questions in using it that might not involve the expertise of systems experts.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Sure, but the damage is done and people may have based their decisions to put the question on hold on this derision towards me. What was said was direct and personal speculation on my skills.

Comment: @Omega This does not appear to be one of them, particularly in the eyes of the experts on that topic.  They felt that this was a sysadmin question.  You should be asking it in the appropriate site for such a topic.

Comment: @Servy - The answer to the question is likely to result in a development item, not a deployment consideration.

Comment: @Omega I can't speak to other voters; but I would *never* vote on a question based on its answers. Posts stand on their own.

Comment: @Omega Your understanding of the topic is crucial information when answering the question.  Understanding what you do and don't know is essential to learning how to solve a problem.  Pretending that you don't lack information, or refusing to discuss what information is lacking that caused the problem are only inhibiting your ability to learn and solve your problem.  Rather than being offended at being told you're not perfect, be grateful for the direction and understanding of what you need to learn.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Which is why I'm here.

Comment: @Servy - Your last comment seems like a non-sequitur.  Is also very similar to what creack was doing which is not looking at what I said, just trying to re-educate me into complaince.

Comment: wait, is this about me?  Because you started it.  If it is.

Comment: @Will Ironically, your statement does not seem to pass Mr. Rogers' reading test.

Comment: I agree there is an epidemic of high rep people being rude/abusive/otherwise-breaking-the-rules and came here by searching for other experiences, but I really have to say, this person's comment doesn't even hit the top 50th percentile. There are so many better examples but I'm personally reluctant to call them out by name for the can of worms that can open.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the record, this was the entire sequence of comments on the answer (don't ask me about the formatting):

[image: Deleted comments]

and your (now deleted) comment on the question read as follows:

> This "on hold" status is very contrived and obviously motivated by creack's realization that he handled his response very poorly.  I'm disappointed to see SO become political like this.   As it pertains to "programming tools", I am talking specifically about docker.  A tool used over the course of developing a project.

I think you're reading a little more into this than was present. I don't see creack personally attacking you, and they weren't the only one to vote to close that question. I don't think they were targeting you because of a personal interaction.

In any case, I didn't agree with the close reason, so I reopened the question.

Comment: You reopen, but then a bunch of people have gone and re-closed it. Does any of this not seem excessive?  It's even been closed for a reason that isn't fully established as applicable...

Comment: It also appears that the only ones voting to close are those who have been trolling me here.  Serious misgivings over abusive moderation. I have not done anything wrong...

Comment: Oh good lord, I gotta fix that deleted comment layout. Tomorrow.

Comment: @AnnaLear Out of curiosity: Is that a network-wide problem? The layout looks perfectly fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Doorknob Network-wide, Safari only. Same issue as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275151/missing-space-bug-in-comments-on-osx.

Comment: Every time a see an @AnnaLear post on meta, she's always fixing something.  :-D

Comment: @Brad I long for the good ol' days when my meta posts were all about just having opinions on stuff. ;)

Answer (score 8):

1. Yes, voting to close and answering a question are contradictory actions, but to do something that would prevent that would probably make the system more cumbersome to use than it needs to be.
2. I'm not seeing anything particularly rude in his answer, and if he left some rude comments and they're deleted, then the system works.  That's what moderators do with non-constructive comments anyway.  They delete them.

Comment: I don't need the comments back, but they definitely would have helped in establishing my concerns.

Comment: @Omega the moderators can still see deleted comments, and the only thing that moderators do about non-extreme insulting comments in the first place is delete them

Comment: All but the last comment was [copied to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/64666) if anyone cares.

Comment: @Omega If there were inappropriate comments and they were deleted, then all is well with the world and the system works.  If not, then there was no problem to begin with.  Either way, nothing to see here.

Comment: Except for the possibly-construed-as-endearing smiling faces, the comments read like an average disagreement.

Comment: @Servy - The question still needs to be restored.

Comment: @Omega And any deleted comments aren't relevant to that discussion.